# Typing in a game?

Tags: mesh, scripting

I made my own little... I guess one could call it a pictogram sort of language?

I want to be able to type it in a blender game, I've already made all the characters/letters but I'm not too sure on how to do the game logic.

I basically want to make this "game" just to quickly generate words/sentences with my made up characters. xD

Idk. How can I make it to where when I press a letter the corresponding mesh appears? And how can I make a space to type a new word?

I'm hoping there's a way to do this without coding, a way with just Blender's built in game logic or something?

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: Well, I think that the Sensor in the Game Logic view would be Keybaord and the Controller would be And. Pretty sure that part is simple. The Actuator might be Edit Object with Add Object? But it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I did some options wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without at least a little bit of python, but... I suggest taking your characters and turning them into an actual font. This can be done for free on several websites. You can then have a text object display its text using your new font, and therefore just change the value of the text object instead of spawning in new meshes.

Comment: But the format on how the words would be typed is different then what happens when we're typing here. x3 But I suppose I can't avoid python.

Comment: Typed differently? How? If you mean you want to press D to get A then you can just move the A character to the D slot while making the actual font.

Comment: I meant instead of the letters appearing side by side like they do normally in word or other text documents, they overlap in a specific way.

Comment: Hmm okay, does each character overlap differently to each other? If they all overlap the same then I think there is a setting in the text object settings which lets you change that.

Comment: There might be a way with the game logic to generate an object (in this case a letter) at the location of an Empty and then move the Empty over by one character-width so it will be ready for the next letter. All hypothetical; haven't tried this myself.